# problem with my custom listview acivity wise holder button click

Tags: java, android, listview

Actually I am trying to make an application using custom list view.

In this application when main activity will initialize then will appear a list view,
then when user will click list item then get position wise will open different activity... then in different activity will appear same new listView, so far I have completed.

but after when click list item form different activity then will open another activity but there coming same activity as per main activity position.

**

### **Now please help me, How I can control holder.ListButton click as per activity wise...**

**

here is my CustomBaseAdapter source code...

```
    package com.sbappstore.romjanbanglacalendar;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.blogspot.atifsoftwares.animatoolib.Animatoo;

import java.lang.annotation.Target;

public class CustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    String[] Name_of_District;
    Context context;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    //Constructor
    public CustomBaseAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, String[] Names_of_District){

        Name_of_District = Names_of_District;
        context = mainActivity;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    //Constructor
    public CustomBaseAdapter(DhakaDistrict dhakaDistrict, String[] dhakaDistrictNames) {
        Name_of_District = dhakaDistrictNames;
        context = dhakaDistrict;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    //Constructor
    public CustomBaseAdapter(BorishalDistrict borishalDistrict, String[] borishaDistrictNames) {
        Name_of_District = borishaDistrictNames;
        context = borishalDistrict;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    //Constructor
    public CustomBaseAdapter(ChattogramDistrict chattogramDistrict, String[] chattogramDistrictNames) {
        Name_of_District = chattogramDistrictNames;
        context = chattogramDistrict;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    //Constructor
    public CustomBaseAdapter(KhulnaDistrict khulnaDistrict, String[] khulnaDistrictNames) {
        Name_of_District = khulnaDistrictNames;
        context = khulnaDistrict;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    //Constructor
    public CustomBaseAdapter(MoymonsinghDistrict moymonsinghDistrict, String[] moymonsinghDistrictNames) {
        Name_of_District = moymonsinghDistrictNames;
        context = moymonsinghDistrict;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    //Constructor
    public CustomBaseAdapter(ProyojoniyoDua proyojoniyoDua, String[] dua) {
        Name_of_District = dua;
        context = proyojoniyoDua;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    //Constructor
    public CustomBaseAdapter(QuranHadith quranHadith, String[] hadithQuran) {
        Name_of_District = hadithQuran;
        context = quranHadith;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    //Constructor
    public CustomBaseAdapter(RajshahiDistrict rajshahiDistrict, String[] rajshahiDistrictNames) {
        Name_of_District = rajshahiDistrictNames;
        context = rajshahiDistrict;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    //Constructor
    public CustomBaseAdapter(RangporDistrict rangporDistrict, String[] rongpurDistrictNames) {
        Name_of_District = rongpurDistrictNames;
        context = rangporDistrict;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    //Constructor
    public CustomBaseAdapter(RomjanerKhaddavash romjanerKhaddavash, String[] khaddavvash) {
        Name_of_District = khaddavvash;
        context = romjanerKhaddavash;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    //Constructor
    public CustomBaseAdapter(SylhetDistrict sylhetDistrict, String[] sylhetDistrictNames) {
        Name_of_District = sylhetDistrictNames;
        context = sylhetDistrict;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    //Constructor
    public CustomBaseAdapter(ArticleMasyala articleMasyala, String[] masayla) {
        Name_of_District = masayla;
        context = articleMasyala;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Name_of_District.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    public class MyHolder{
        Button ListButton;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final MyHolder holder = new MyHolder();
        final View view;

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list, null);
        holder.ListButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.ListButton);
        holder.ListButton.setText(Name_of_District[position]);


        holder.ListButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View customView) {
               int id = customView.getId();

                if (position==0) {
                    //Toast.makeText(context,"Position 0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    context.startActivity(new Intent(context,DhakaDistrict.class));
                    Animatoo.animateSlideLeft(context);
                }
                if (position==1) {
                    context.startActivity(new Intent(context,ChattogramDistrict.class));
                    Animatoo.animateSlideLeft(context);
                }
                if (position==2) {
                    context.startActivity(new Intent(context,SylhetDistrict.class));
                    Animatoo.animateSlideLeft(context);
                }
                if (position==3) {
                    context.startActivity(new Intent(context,BorishalDistrict.class));
                    Animatoo.animateSlideLeft(context);
                }
                if (position==4) {
                    context.startActivity(new Intent(context,MoymonsinghDistrict.class));
                    Animatoo.animateSlideLeft(context);
                }
                if (position==5) {
                    context.startActivity(new Intent(context,RajshahiDistrict.class));
                    Animatoo.animateSlideLeft(context);
                }
                if (position==6) {
                    context.startActivity(new Intent(context,KhulnaDistrict.class));
                    Animatoo.animateSlideLeft(context);
                }
                if (position==7) {
                    context.startActivity(new Intent(context,RangporDistrict.class));
                    Animatoo.animateSlideLeft(context);
                }
                if (position==8) {
                    context.startActivity(new Intent(context,ProyojoniyoDua.class));
                    Animatoo.animateSlideLeft(context);
                }
                if (position==9) {
                    context.startActivity(new Intent(context,QuranHadith.class));
                    Animatoo.animateSlideLeft(context);
                }
                if (position==10) {
                    context.startActivity(new Intent(context,ArticleMasyala.class));
                    Animatoo.animateSlideLeft(context);
                }
                if (position==11) {
                    context.startActivity(new Intent(context,RomjanerKhaddavash.class));
                    Animatoo.animateSlideLeft(context);
                }
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

Here is my main_activity.java

```
<pre><code>
    package com.sbappstore.romjanbanglacalendar;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends ToolbarAdapter {

    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);


        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewId);
        String[] districtNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.District_Names);

        CustomBaseAdapter adapter = new CustomBaseAdapter(this,districtNames);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
<pre><code>
```

others all activity as like bellow...

```
<pre><code>
    package com.sbappstore.romjanbanglacalendar;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.widget.ListView;

public class DhakaDistrict extends ToolbarAdapter {
    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dhaka_district);

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("ঢাকা বিভাগ");

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewId);
        String[] dhakaDistrictNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Dhaka_District_Names);

        CustomBaseAdapter adapter = new CustomBaseAdapter(this,dhakaDistrictNames);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using `singleTask` or `singleInstance` for these activities?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It seems that you have mistake with your `ViewHolder`. `ViewHolder` is memory object that holding your view data. But you are creating `ViewHolder` every `getView`. I suggest you use `RecyclerView`.

Answer (score 0):

First, Use `RecyclerView`. `ListView` is old one, and `RecyclerView` has better structure.

Second, do not use position as ID. In your case, there will be no problem. But position can be changed, so it is dangerous.

The code below is my suggestion, and it is not a complete code but just focused on how to use `ViewHolder` pattern.

```
public class MyHolder {
    // DO NOT use position as ID. I suggest you to use district name as ID.
    String districtName; 
    Button ListButton;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    MyHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new MyHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list, null);
        holder.ListButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.ListButton);
        holder.ListButton.setText(Name_of_District[position]);

        holder.districtName = ""; // may be Name_of_District[position]

        // Set your onClick listener here. Use districtName is ID. 
        holder.ListButton.setOnClickListener();

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (MyHolder)convertView.getTag()
    }

    // Write rest of code here

    return convertView;
}
```